# Jira over SSL gives a blank page with symbols

Tags: ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate, https, jira

My attempts to configure Jira to work over SSL have not been successful so far. I have followed the steps at: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/running-jira-over-ssl-or-https-124008.html

My certificate seems to be working (although self-signed).
`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect flokkstudios.com:8443` gives the appropriate certificate results.

However when I try `curl flokkstudios.com:8443` or browse to the url/port using Firefox I am getting weird symbols.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what is going on and what I could possibly do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

https://flokkstudios.com:8443

When using a non standard https port, like 8443, you need to add https in the URL. Otherwise the browser supposes it's http traffic, non encrypted, and thus displays encrypted content directly, which results in these strange characters.

Comment: No problem. I had the exact same problem myself a while ago.